# Boostrap Nav-Bar Toggle Button Not Working on Certain Pages

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I am using the below navigation bar on a number of ASPX pages.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">

        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="Home.aspx">Home</a>
            </div>

            <div class="w3-container">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="w3-dropdown-hover">
                            <a href="News.aspx">News</a>
                            <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-white w3-card-4">
                                <a href="News.aspx">Latest News</a>
                                <a href="NewsArchive.aspx">News Archive</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="w3-dropdown-hover">
                            <a href="Sports.aspx">Sports</a>
                            <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-white w3-card-4">
                                <a href="#">GAA</a>
                                <a href="#">Camogie</a>
                                <a href="#">Ladies Football</a>
                                <a href="#">Richmond Soccer</a>
                                <a href="#">Fishing</a>
                                <a href="#">Restocking Association</a>
                                <a href="#">Walking Club</a>
                                <a href="#">Gun Club</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="w3-dropdown-hover">
                            <a href="ViewEvents.aspx">Groups</a>
                            <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-white w3-card-4">
                                <a href="#">Scouts</a>
                                <a href="#">ICA</a>
                                <a href="#">Red Cross</a>
                                <a href="#">CFR</a>
                                <a href="#">Vincent de Paul</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="Church.aspx">Church of St. James</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Ballinora N.S.</a></li>
                        <li><a href="LocalProducts.aspx">Local Business</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Gardening.aspx">Gardening</a></li>
                        <li class="w3-dropdown-hover">
                            <a href="CommunityAssociation.aspx">Comm. Association</a>
                            <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-white w3-card-4">
                                <a href="#">Environment</a>
                                <a href="#">Social Inclusion</a>
                                <a href="#">Infrastructure</a>
                                <a href="#">Recreation</a>
                                <a href="#">Culture & Heritage</a>
                                <a href="#">Roads & Road Safety</a>
                                <a href="#">Safety & Security</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="Admin.aspx">Admin</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
```

When I minimize the screen on all pages, the navigation bar collapses & displays like so:

[image: scrn1]

Then, when I click the button at the top right, on some pages, the menu is displayed like this:

[image: scrn2]

However, this only works on two of my pages, Sports.aspx and ViewEvents.aspx

On the other pages, the menu is collapsing, but when I click the top-right button, nothing happens.

Any thoughts??

Answer (score 1):

Found it, I forgot to add the below code inside the  section:

```
        <!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```